# Parse dynamic json expression to get value

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, expression

I created a user control called ticker that is used in my trading program.  It takes a url property that controls where it gets its prices from. A few example urls are:

```
coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/buy
btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker
www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/
```

I want the **user** to be able to change which exchange provides json object and also specify the javascript expression to find the value like this:

```
json.total.amount
json.last.buy
json.last
```

etc.  I can find a ton of dynamic examples where dynamic objects are being created, but the javascript expression is known in advance and the value is referenced in C# with json.last for exmple in C#.  I will not know what the expression will be, so how do I get c# to evaluate my expression and store the results in a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**json.net** library allow you to parse json string to dynamic object easily.

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse("{}");
```

For more information, [LINQ to JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm)